# Creating realtime document for a folder

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I'd like to create a realtime model holding the name, description and some other properties for a drive folder.
When I try to create the realtime document with the folder id I get a "Bad request".
Is creating realtime models for folders supported?

Comment: It seems like this now works, at least for me.  Can you try again and update the question?